# Can we prove multivariable functions continuous like this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

In single variable calculus for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x_0$ we need to have $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 - h) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 + h) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0)$ and it should be well defined at that point.

Since I am venturing new into multivariable calculus I wanted to know if we can use this method too in proving a multivariable function continuous ? I mean like to prove $f(x, y, z)$ to be continuous at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ do we follow the above method here like $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 - h, y_0 - h, z_0 - h) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 + h, y_0 + h, z_0 + h) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 , y_0, z_0)$

Since I did not find my textbook following this method for any of its examples I decided to ask here.

Comment: In general, no. The above just tests continuity on the line $(x_0,y_0,z_0)+ t (1,1,1)$, you need something like $\lim_{(h_x,h_y,h_z) \to 0} f(x_0+h_x, y_0+h_y,z_0+h_z)$.

Comment: "The above just tests continuity on the line $(x_0,y_0,z_0)+ t (1,1,1)$" you said, just if you could elaborate a bit about how this happens and so if I replace the notion $lim_{h \to 0}$ with $\lim_{(h_x,h_y,h_z) \to 0}$, then it would work ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, if you just vary $h$ you are looking at the values of $f$ on the line $(x_0+h, y_0+h,z_0+h)$ which is the line through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ along the direction $(1,1,1)$. The function $f$ can have arbitrary values off this line without affecting the limit above. If you use the $(h_x,h_y,h_z) \to 0$ then you can use this to show continuity.

Answer (score 1):

For $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, to prove that $f$ is continuous at $\pmb x_0$, it is sufficient to show that $f(\pmb x)\to f(\pmb x_0)$ whenever $d(\pmb x,\pmb x_0)\to0$, where $d:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is any continuous function such that $d(x_1,...,x_n,\pmb x_0)\to0$ forces $x_1,...,x_n$ to go simultaneously to the corresponding components of $\pmb x_0$. Convenient forms of such $f$ are $f(\pmb x,\pmb y)=|x_1-y_1|+\cdots+|x_n-y_n|$ or  $f(\pmb x,\pmb y)=(x_1-y_1)^2+\cdots+(x_n-y_n)^2$.